# yeoman generator font awesome

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, font-awesome, yeoman-generator

I created a mobile application with the yeoman mobile-generator. 
Now I want to add font awesome. I tried [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/25), but not really works in the compiling process. A small advice or experience would be great

Okay, it's really a bit unclear. Sorry.  
The compiling process works, but console says 404 not founds for the fonts. 
It's not really clear to me how is a good way to do this. Creating the CSS from the scss files, implemeted the .min.css in the index.html with "<-- build: ... -->" or something else?!

When I add this in my main .scss file the the fonts would not be found.

```
$fontAwesomePath: "../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts";
@import '../bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

Grunt copies and renames the font files f.e. to:

```
5a6b8fb8.FontAwesome
```

Comment: If you have compiler issues, post the errors... Nobody will be able to help you if you don't do a little effort to make your question clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, 
seems I could fixed this with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310885/1364685).
Installed font awesome with bower:

```
bower install --save font-awesome
```

Then simply this line in the index.html fixed my problem.

```
<!-- build:css styles/vendor/fontawesome.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Thanks @OddEssay and @bpaul for our help!!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like grunt rev https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev is renaming your font file. Just look for something like this in your Gruntfile:

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
...
```

remove the fonts line and you should be okay.

Comment: No problem, Let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you use to copy the font files to the dist folder? did you add a copy task?

Comment: Yes, I just add styles/fonts/* to the src under the copy task: `src: ['*.{ico,png,txt}', '.htaccess', 'images/{,*/}*.{webp}', 'styles/fonts/*']`

Answer (score 1):

@importing the scss takes care of the CSS side of things, but I think you also need to move the assests to a location the browser can access them, so [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) would do the job perfectly. So if your webroot is `public` Something like:

```
copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          {expand: true, cwd: '../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts', src: ['*.*'], dest: 'public/fonts'}
               ]
      }
```

Comment: thanks. but the problem I think is, that grunt renames the fonts, and the original font path is not the right one.

Comment: The files do need to be copied but in this case it seems the problem is with with grunt rev. See my answer below.