# Font-awesome not working with yeoman generator pushed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using the Yeoman generator "angular-fullstack".  With a freshly generated "angular-fullstack" scaffold, I perform a
`bower install --save components-font-awesome` then add in a font-awesome icon to the main.html template, build and push it up to heroku, and I see a grey box where the icon should be.

However, if I perform a `grunt serve` locally, I can see the icon as I expect.

I don't know if this is a Yeoman Angular-fullstack issue, grunt issue, font-awesome issue or Heroku issue so I'm throwing it out there.  Maybe someone can help limit this down.

**Note**: I'm using "components-font-awesome" instead of "font-awesome" because grunt won't build font-awesome correctly so it was advised to use the shim.

What I see when served locally: [image]

What I see when built and pushed to heroku:[image]

Comment: please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310382/fontawesome-is-not-working-when-project-is-built-with-grunt/21310885#21310885

Comment: that didn't help 1. I don't get any error in my console.  2. I already tried to declare the css outside my bower build area 3.  I tried moving the fonts dir to under dist.   I still get a grey box.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  Sorry Michael, that answer was good... it just needed to click in my head.  I'll elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this version of the Yeoman angular-fullstack generator, the `grunt build` command builds the delivered files under the `dist` directory.  The other stackoverflow answer (that was referenced in the comments above) hinted to put the font-awesome `fonts` directory directly under the `dist` level.  However, the served files are under `dist/public`.  Therefore, it's under the `public` directory where the `fonts` directory currently exists and the font-awesome font files should be placed.

To make this work with the existing `grunt build`, I pre-copied the font-awesome font files into the `app/fonts` directory.  This way, the `grunt build` automatically copies the files into the `dist/public/fonts` directory.

Comment: FYI, as of May 13th, 2014 not everything in "app" is copied over to dist. In my grunt file, I had a copy task that was copying over "fonts".  Thats the default, in my particular case, I had "font" referenced in all my files. So change it based on what you need copied over, don't be afraid to mess around in the gruntfile.js. +1 padawanIvn for explaining

Comment: To complement: just like bootstrap copies its fonts in Gruntfile.js, you should add `{ expand: true, cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/font-awesome', src: 'fonts/*', dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>' }` to your Gruntfile 'copy.dist.files' entry

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci +1 you should make that a separate answer.

Comment: The answer is to "Christophe".

Answer (score 7):

To complement the accepted answer, here is the way to go:

Add the following to `Gruntfile.js` in the `copy.dist.files` section:

```
{ 
  expand: true,
  cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/font-awesome', 
  src: 'fonts/*', 
  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>' 
}
```

I created a distinct answer as suggested by other comments.

Comment: Did not work exactly like that, so I did the way it was done for bootstrap:           `cwd: '.',
          src: 'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'`

Comment: Has font-awesome changed its bower component directory? I see you are using `components-font-awesome` instead of `font-awesome`. I guess you can do it that way if you don't put `expand: true`, otherwise I would guess it is the same except the name of the component might have changed.

Comment: You are right, I remember I used the `components-font-awesome` shim because well... there was another issue with `font-awesome`. Anyway, I voted for your solution; the reader can simply adjust the folders if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Christophe's version didn't work for me.

This worked for me:

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
  src: 'fonts/*',
  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for using font-awesome.css

This is what worked for me:

If install font-awesome via bower, open "bower_components/font-awesome/bower.json" and find the following block of code:

```
"main": [
    "less/font-awesome.less",
    "scss/font-awesome.scss"
],
```

Add the CSS to this "main" node array:

```
"main": [
    "less/font-awesome.less",
    "scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

Start your server, or stop/start if it's already running, and font-awesome css 'should' now be injected.