# Glyphicons not appearing after running grunt in angular generator

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

When you run `grunt` to build the app, the vendor.css file created in the `dist` folder 'mis-links' the glyphicons as `/app/bower_componenets/.../glyphicons-...` instead of `../fonts/glyphicons-...`

Answer (score 2):

In `Gruntfile.js` comment out the following line to fix this issue:

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    //root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/645