# Grunt copy and fontawesome fonts

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy, font-awesome-4

I have installed **fontawesome** with bower and am using grunt's "grunt-contrib-copy" to copy it to a diff directory.

When I manually copy it, the font works ... but, when grunt does it, they do not work.

Now, I checked the files, and I noticed grunt's copy does the work, it increases the file size !

The file sizes from fontawesome :

```
  85908  FontAwesome.otf
  56006  fontawesome-webfont.eot
 287007  fontawesome-webfont.svg
 112160  fontawesome-webfont.ttf
  65452  fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

The file sizes after grunt copied them :

```
 163355  FontAwesome.otf
 101913  fontawesome-webfont.eot
 287008  fontawesome-webfont.svg
 143313  fontawesome-webfont.ttf
 120957  fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

Here i my gruntfile.js snippet :

```
      'fontawesome-fonts': {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'public/vendor/fontawesome/fonts',
        src: '*',
        dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'fonts')
      }
```

Comment: Did you try searching -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310382/fontawesome-is-not-working-when-project-is-built-with-grunt

Comment: Yes, I saw that question earlier ... It is a completely different error from mine and not applicable here

Comment: Am I right that your problem is in the [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) changes files size? Which OS and file system do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though grunt-copy is incapable of copying binary files correctly (sometimes?)

So, it is recommended to not use it for binary files - images, music, videos, fonts, etc.

EDIT:
One possible method of fixing this which worked for me was as mentioned at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/64, use `processContent: false` or `processContentExclude: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd}']` in the `options` section of `copy`.

Comment: what do we use then for copying these files?

Comment: You can use `processContentExclude` which tells grunt-copy that it should not touch specific files other than copying it - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/64

Comment: It actually  turned to be something completely different in my case.  Font files were already getting copied just fine.