# How to Install fontawesome to meanjs project

Tags: html, css, node.js, font-awesome, meanjs

I changed `bower.json` file to install `FontAwesome` like below and run `npm` install.
It installed `FontAwesome 4.3.0.`
I added the `font-awesome.css` by using `confg/env/all.js`. In the browser I can see the `font-awesome.css` has added to the `html`. But I can not see fonts on the web page. By inspecting element I could not found any font loaded.

[image]

Fonts are already on fonts folder of font-awesome in my source.
[image]

Comment: You have to paste font files in your fonts folder.

Comment: @UI-UX they are already in fonts folder in my source.

Comment: fonts folder must be a folder up to fontawesome.css. Or reconfigure in variable.scss file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310382/fontawesome-is-not-working-when-project-is-built-with-grunt

Answer (score 0):

Since I can see the fonts exist in your project structure this appears to be an issue with the font path.

As you can see in the first screenshot the font path is pointed to:

```
@font-face {
    src: url ('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
```

however if you look at your project structure the fonts actually exist in the following location:

```
@font-face {
    src: url ('../fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
```

You will need to update the font path in your css stylesheet to "../fontawesome/fonts" in order for the font resources to be located and loaded into the browser.

Comment: Thank You @ashk3l I think that wasn't the error. your answer is not correct. Please check I have set the path correctly.

Comment: The font path would only be correct if your fonts folder was at the root of your project which it isn't.  Here is an example on file paths (https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) that will help you to understand the problem. I believe you are getting confused because you may believe that the stylesheet is relative to the fonts folder below it but when it is loaded into the browser it is relative to the project root.