# Font awesome URL not coded in main.css for grunt dist

Tags: gruntjs, font-awesome

I used Yeoman to scaffold my project and Bower to install Font Awesome. I added

```
$fa-font-path: "../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/";
@import "../bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

to `app/styles/style.css`

The fonts showed during development but not in the deployed stage where I used `grunt dist` to pack my files for deployment. I could see the font-awesome URLs in my `dist/styles/59268e94.main.css` were pointing to `/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/` whereas Bootsrap's glyphicons URLs were changed to a new location e.g. `@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(../styles/fonts/2ad0632b.glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)`. I think this could be the problem.

How can I get my web application to work with Font Awesome? Thanks.

Update #1 (26/3)

While waiting for a better answer and as to why Font Awesome SCSS fonts' URL were not changed like those in Bootstraps SCSS, I decided to remove "renaming the fonts files" task from Gruntfile.js as suggested by @bpaul in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396651/185514

Comment: eventually this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775497/yeoman-generator-font-awesome

Comment: not good. i added this  <!-- build:css styles/vendor/fontawesome.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.css">
<!-- endbuild --> 

to index.html and built.it complained that "Running "cssmin:dist/styles/vendor/fontawesome.css" (cssmin) task
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty."

Comment: I can see why not renaming the fonts files helps. I don't why Bootstrap fonts worked but not Font Awesome. Is there a builtin process to Bootstrap components?